# PyQt: reduce boilerplate for computational module GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, boilerplate

I have a module for a physical process simulation. Now I want to do a GUI for it. I've used PyQt to create application, which allows to control calculation, its parameters and graphical output. But there is a problem - if I want to add some new feature to simulation, then in addition to coding it in computational module, I need to create wrapper function for calling it in GUI module, GUI element for calling it, set up GUI representation and bind it to the function I need. That's annoying, because I need to write an amount of obvious code instead of working on logic. I have a few ideas on automatization of process, but first I want to ask: are there some recommended ways to reduce this boilerplate work?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to GUI programming! :)

In PyQt, you can slightly reduce the amount of boilerplate by [autoconnecting slots by name](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name). 
You can also create any GUI element at runtime, without resorting to QtDesigner, so you can do things like generate a list of checkboxes in a `for` loop.